# accepted ways of submitting and retrieving data using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

what is the most accepted way of retrieving data without reloading, ive seen tutorials use `echo encode_json(array)`, the tutorial im following doesnt use it, instead.. i think he opts to get the `HTML` area of a specific PHP page.

my **index.php**

```
 $("#button").click(function() {
  ... some code here ....

      $.ajax
        ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update.php",
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'html',
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) 
          {
            $("#posts").prepend(html); 
            $("#posts").slideDown("slow");  
            document.getElementById('content').value=''; 
            document.getElementById('content').focus();
          }
        });
  });
```

Upon success, I want to retrieve the data from my MYSQL and print it on my `#posts` DIV.

my **update.php** includes

- inserting data into mysql
- selects/retrieve data from mysql
- echoes the data from mysql_query

  ```
  <?php 
    include("connect.php");
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
      $status = $_POST['status']; //get textarea value
      mysql_query("insert into messages (msg) values ('$status')");
    }

      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT msg,msg_id FROM messages order by msg_id desc");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
      $msg = $row['msg'];
      $msg_id = $row['msg_id'];


  ?>

    <!-- get this part -->

    <li id="posts"> 
     id:<?php echo $msg_id; ?>
     text: <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </li>
  ```

basically, i just want to submit a post, and displays **all** the posts without reloading.

Comment: There is no best way. It depends on your application. One consideration is bandwidth. It is more efficient to send small chinks of data than fully structured HTML fragments. But I wouldn't worry about that if the data load is just a few K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track.
However you are trying to insert something with an `id="posts"` into an element which is already on the page with the same ID which is not correct.
Perhaps make a wrapper div with a class of `posts-container` and then you can return say this from PHP:

```
<li class="post"> 
   id:<?php echo $msg_id; ?>
   text: <?php echo $msg; ?>
</li>
```

and add it to your page like this:

```
$.ajax
        ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update.php",
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'html',
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) 
          {
            $(".post-container").prepend(html); 
            $(".post-container").slideDown("slow");  
            document.getElementById('content').value=''; 
            document.getElementById('content').focus();
          },
          //adding an error function
          error: function(error){
              //do whatever you need to handle you error here
              console.log(error);
          }
        });
```

Comment: `success: function(html)` is this the code that retrieves/get the html part of the **update.php**? and then prints it inside the ".post-container"?

Comment: Yes correct.  As long as there isn't an error on the serverside, youre Ajax calls' `success` function will get called, else it will call the `error` function which you happen to be missing.  I'll edit the above to give you an idea.  Then you can use that returned data to do whatever with.
According to the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) since you've specified that your dataType is html you're going to get this in your success function `"html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.`

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, im sorry if this already too much asking. but, i really cant get the code work. i checked the console log and there were no errors displayed. i changed my code according to your post. my html from my other page doesnt display on my index via ajax

Comment: OK, have a look at this fiddle.  I've condensed the problem somewhat and we can't emulate AJAX across domains so have had to cheat a little but I have tested locally with the ajax function and it works the same.  http://jsfiddle.net/pPqw6/